# Can we add <div id="api"></div> embedded Angular/SPA page url to Azure AD B2C Endpoint?

Tags: html, angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

According to official documentation, we can use HTML Template(static html) to customize login using Azure AD B2C, my question is it possible to embed Angular/SPA page url with "div id='api'" in Azure B2C Login Endpoint/ Custom page uri? I only see examples of embedding simple HTML page url and not angular generated HTML url. Is it technically feasible currently?
I know there are other ways as shown in official documentation where the flows go from website to B2C i.e. we can use redirect or popup. But I need the B2C endpoint to show my embedded angular page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#guidelines-for-using-javascript

> JavaScript frameworks:
> Azure AD B2C uses a specific version of jQuery. Don’t include another version of jQuery. Using more than one version on the same page causes issues.
> Using RequireJS isn't supported.
> Most JavaScript frameworks are not supported by Azure AD B2C.

You can try to embed Angular in your custom HTML endpoint, but there’s no guarantee it will work due to the number of dependencies it brings.

Comment: From the official documentation -"Most JavaScript frameworks are not supported by Azure AD B2C." makes be suspect that SPA HTML pages are not supported by B2C HTML Template.